# Handmade DNS root NS query fails to 1.1.1.1 but succeeds to 8.8.8.8

Tags: domain-name-system

For educational purposes I'm sending handmade packets to query root NS using python. The expectation is to get similar results as `dig NS . @1.1.1.1`.

*The following is relevant only to `NS .` as any other `NS <domain>` works as expected.*

Given the following packet structure:

```
(Pdb) req
                     1
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|             0x28c2            |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|0|  0x0  |0|0|1|0|  0  |  0x0  |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|             0x0001            |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|             0x0000            |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|             0x0000            |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|             0x0000            |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+<--
/                               /
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|             0x0002            |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|             0x0001            |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+<--

(Pdb) bytes(req)
b'(\xc2\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x01'
```

Then sending it to cloudflare `1.1.1.1` and google `8.8.8.8`

```
(Pdb) len(req.send(("8.8.8.8", 53)).records)
13

(Pdb) len(req.send(("1.1.1.1", 53)).records)
0
```

Inspecting the query sent via `dig` in Wireshark shows the exact same fields as in the python query above, except that `dig` sends an additional `edns` record.

I'm trying to find out why is the above query working with `8.8.8.8` but failing `1.1.1.1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you adapt your `dig` command line to send an equally minimal version of this query, you get:

```
$ dig . NS +noedns +ignore @1.1.1.1

; <<>> DiG 9.18.16-1~deb12u1-Debian <<>> . NS +noedns +ignore @1.1.1.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 42553
;; flags: qr tc rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;.                              IN      NS

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Sun Jul 30 16:11:19 CEST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 17

$
```

Ie, with `1.1.1.1` you get an (empty) truncated response (note the `TC` flag).
I'm not sure *why* they do not simply serve the `NS` rrset alone in this case as that would fit, but that is the behavior of `1.1.1.1` that leads up to your question.

Without EDNS0 the answer size is limited to 512 bytes, with EDNS0 the client can indicate a larger message size they can accept (1232 bytes is typical these days).

(`+noedns` being the actual change to the query, `+ignore` only to show the truncation message itself rather than trying to get the full answer via TCP instead)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was missing. Running `dig . NS +noedns @1.1.1.1` returns `MSG SIZE  rcvd: 800`, on the other hand `dig . NS +noedns @8.8.8.8` returns `MSG SIZE  rcvd: 228`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in additional sections of `1.1.1.1` they return A and AAAA records for each of the 13 NS